# Why is my inter vlan trunk routing not working?

Tags: routing, vlan, trunk

I'm using packet tracer. I have the following configuration :

On switch 2950-24

- VLAN 99

  - .
  - interface assigned to it is fa 0/1
  - PC 1 has ip 10.10.10.2 with default gateway 10.10.10.3. PC 1 is connected to fa 0/1.
- VLAN 100

  - .
  - interface assigned to it is fa 0/2
  - - PC 2 has ip 10.100.100.2 with default gateway 10.100.100.3. PC 2 is connected to fa 0/2.
- On the switch, interface fa 0/3 is set to trunk mode
- Routeur 2621-XM

  - Interface fa 0/0 is up and connected to switch fa 0/3
  - sub interface fa 0/0.2 has ip 10.10.10.3
  - sub interface fa 0/0.3 has ip 10.100.100.3

With all those settings, all lights are green. BUT the problem is that PC1 cannot ping PC 2

Below is an image of the configuration

[image: Immage of my configuration]

**Below is my Router and switch configuration**

```
Current configuration : 1167 bytes
!
version 12.1
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname Switch
!
!
!
spanning-tree mode pvst
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 switchport access vlan 99
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/2
 switchport access vlan 100
 switchport mode access
!
interface FastEthernet0/3
 switchport mode trunk

!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Vlan99
 mac-address 0060.2fbb.3401
 no ip address
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
line vty 5 15
 login
!
!
!
end
```

And now my router configuration

```
Current configuration : 752 bytes
!
version 12.2
no service timestamps log datetime msec
no service timestamps debug datetime msec
no service password-encryption
!
hostname ROUTER
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
no ip cef
no ipv6 cef
!
!

interface FastEthernet0/0
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 2
 ip address 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.3
 encapsulation dot1Q 3
 ip address 10.100.100.3 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 no ip address
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/0
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
interface Serial0/1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
ip classless
!
ip flow-export version 9
!
!
!
!
!
!
!
line con 0
!
line aux 0
!
line vty 0 4
 login
!
!
!
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mistake in sub-interfaces configuration. As your VLAN ID's is 99 and 100 you should change interface configs respectively:

```
interface FastEthernet0/0.2
 encapsulation dot1Q 99
 ip address 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.0
!
interface FastEthernet0/0.3
 encapsulation dot1Q 100
 ip address 10.100.100.3 255.255.255.0
```

And also verify, that you've created VLAN's on switch by entering in enable mode

```
show vlan
```

on switch and paste output here.

Comment: YES !!!!!!!   **You are the best in the world Andrey**.... It works properly now...  I don't know why `encapsulation dot1Q 99` and `encapsulation dot1Q 100` changes made it work though...

Comment: You have vlans 99 and 100 on your switch, therefore you should use same numbers as dot1q values for your L3 interfaces. In your config was specified id 2 and 3. It might work if you create VLAN 2 and 3 on switch and configure pc's access ports for accessing in vlan 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

may you need to assign the sub-interface on the ***router*** to the proper VLAN

```
int g0/0.2  
encapsulation dot1Q 2

int g0/0.3  
encapsulation dot1Q 3
```

and so you may not need to  interface vlans on the switch

Comment: I did that already.....If you want I'll post my configs so you can see what is wrong.... An I removed ip's from Vlan on the switch... SAme result

Comment: Please see my updated post with my configs

Answer (score 0):

Sub-interfaces configuration is wrong in router . Need to modify subinterface configuration in router as below.

`Router(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0.99`

`Router(config)# encapsulation dot1Q 99`

`Router(config)# ip address 10.10.10.3 255.255.255.0`

`Router(config)#interface FastEthernet0/0.100`

`Router(config)#encapsulation dot1Q 100`

`Router(config)# ip address 10.100.100.3 255.255.255.0`

Comment: Hi. This was a school project 3 years ago. Thanks for your answer. Hopefully it will help someone in the community